# making use of mousemove, mousedown, and mouseup with a click and drag div

Tags: javascript, jquery, client-side

I cant quite seem to get it working, but what i want to do is to be able to have something attached to my mouse, then when i mousedown unbind the click but then rebind it to moves the width and height instead of the top and left.  attempt is as follows:

```
$(document).mousemove(function(mouseEvent) {
    creationTagBool = true;
    n.show();
    n.css("left", mouseEvent.pageX);
    n.css("top", mouseEvent.pageY);
}).mousedown(function(mouseEvent) {
    if (creationTagBool) {
        $(this).unbind("mousemove");
        creationTagBool = false;
        //draggCon();
        n.css("width", mouseEvent.pageX - n.css("left"));
        n.css("height", mouseEvent.pageY - n.css("top"));
    }

}).mouseup(function(mouseEvent) {
    $(this).unbind("mousedown");
    draggCon();
});​
```

I was actually thinking that it should do something like:
  mousemove, mousedown to unbind and then rebind mousemove, the on mouseup unbind mousemove again.

As i am typing this out, i was thinking this might work so i have to test it quick.  My thought is something like as follows:

```
$(document).mousemove(function(mouseEvent) {
    creationTagBool = true;
    n.show();
    n.css("left", mouseEvent.pageX);
    n.css("top", mouseEvent.pageY);
}).mousedown(function(mouseEvent) {
    if (creationTagBool) {
        $(this).unbind("mousemove");
        creationTagBool = false;
        //draggCon();
        //n.css("width", mouseEvent.pageX - n.css("left"));
        //
        $(this).mousemove(function() {
            n.css("width", mouseEvent.pageX - n.css("left"));
            n.css("height", mouseEvent.pageY - n.css("top"));
        }).mouseup(function() {
            $(this).unbind("mousemove");
            draggCon();
        });
    }
});​
```

Answer (score 0):

Error is width the height and width so when running it, you need to have.  mouseEvent.pageX + n.position().left instead of n.css("left").

When i get that working, it seems to be fine, though a bit slower.  Instead of the click and drag event for the time being, i just checked it to 2 clicks instead.